# Does DataBinding changes an object argument to ByRev?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dictionary, listbox

Hi i'm experimenting with databinding and have some strange things going on here. I have a `MainWindow` and a `VarAssignmentWindow`. I also have a Dictionary where my Data is stored:

```
public Dictionary<String, MDevice> devices = new Dictionary<string,MDevice>();
```

In the `VarAssignmentWindow` i want to change some values inside of the `devices`-Object if i click on an OK button, or do not apply the changes if i hit the Cancel button.

I call the `VarAssignmentWindow` this way:

```
        VarAssignmentWindow window = new VarAssignmentWindow(devices);
        window.Owner = this;
        window.ShowDialog();

        if (window.canceled == false)
        {
            //Save changes if OK was clicked
            devices = window.devices;
        }
```

as you can see i want to overwrite the `MainWindow.devices` with `VarAssignmentWindow.devices` if i hit the OK button, otherwhise nothing **should** happen.

Now here is whats going on inside of the `VarAssignmentWindow` class:

```
    public Dictionary<String, MDevice> devices = new Dictionary<string,MDevice>();
    public bool canceled = true;

    public VarAssignmentWindow(Dictionary<String, MDevice> devices)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.devices = devices; //This seems to be ByRef, but only, if i bind the items to the listbox
        updateListBox();
    }

    private void updateListBox()
    {
        lstVars.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var dev in devices)
        {
            foreach (var vari in dev.Value.savedVarDic)
            {
                lstVars.Items.Add(vari.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    private void cmdOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        canceled = false;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void cmdCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        canceled = true;
        this.Close();
    }
```

**If i change anything inside the ListBox, its always changed in the** `MainWindow.devices` **object too, no matter if i hit cancel or ok.**

To be sure if its a ByRef i made the following test:

```
    public VarAssignmentWindow(Dictionary<String, MDevice> devices)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.devices = devices;
        updateListBox();
        this.devices = null;
    }
    --> devices in MainWindow is null afterwards

    public VarAssignmentWindow(Dictionary<String, MDevice> devices)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.devices = devices;
        //updateListBox();
        this.devices = null;
    }
    --> devices in MainWindow is not null (its what it was before)
```

Is it just a stupid DataBinding mistake i made? please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, data binding does not change an object argument to ByRef. *You* are editing the *same* `devices` collection from your `MainWindow` control. Make a deep copy of the collection *before* passing it to your `VarAssignmentWindow Window`. In this way, if the user wants to cancel, you can simply return the original collection and if they save, then you return the new, edited collection.

Comment: you say i edit the _same_ devices, when i change inside `VarAssignmentWindow` this.devices, so this.devices is just a pointer to `MainWindow.devices`? And wouldnt this be ByRef? Or do you just mean data binding doesnt change because this kind of argument is always ByRef anyway?

Comment: Your second sentence... all objects are passed by reference anyway. You pass the actual object here: `new VarAssignmentWindow(devices);`. Instead of this, try something more like this: `new VarAssignmentWindow(copyOfDevices);`. Clearly though, *you* have to create the `copyOfDevices` clone.

Comment: i used [Alex Burtsev's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically) DeepCopy solution which works great, thank you for filling my knowledge gap (i thought objects are always ByRef but my second experiment fooled me a bit (the last piece of code)) and i still dont know why the devices is not null in the mainwindow class at the last example

Comment: Objects *are* always passed by reference... only `struct`s are passed by value.

Comment: yes but why in my last example devices in `MainWindow` != null?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with that... it *should* be `null`.